# Windows Phone gray transition frame

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a problem with gray transition frames in Windows Phone 7.

I am using Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit and transitions are working fine except for the color. Suddenly, the color of the transitioning frame became gray. For the purposes of my app, I am overriding the app resources, like this:

```
        (App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.White;
        (App.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Black;
```

When I don't do that, the transition frame is black if the theme on the phone is dark, and it's white if the theme on the phone is white. As it should be.

As soon as I set the resources (background and foreground brush), the transition frame becomes **gray** if the theme on the phone is dark, and **white** if the theme on the phone is white.

Any guesses what on Earth is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found what caused this, and it's the most unusual thing. I wasted 4 hours and then realized what was the thing I changed compared to the last version of my app.

I realized that I added the AdDuplex ad control. I have no idea how and why this influences the color of the transition page, but whenever I debug my app using trial mode and display the ad control, the transition page becomes gray. When I am not in trial but "paid" mode, the ad is not visible and the transition page is white.

Removing the AdDuplex control helps. (not such a great solution)